# Arrays printing data into one div rather than looping each one,

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, loops

Hoping you guys can help me, I have been playing around with brewdogs api called punk api.
I have built a search function but whenever the user searches for a word that returns multiple beers it prints them all at once.
Is there anyway to print one title, one tagline, one description, one abv, one pic and then repeat til all have been printed?
It is currently just printing every title in one div then every tag line in one div and so on.
I have also attached an [image to show the results when searched.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOQSk.png)

[image: Second issue]

```js
function beerAsk(e) {
  clear();
  const beerage = document.getElementById("BeerInputSearch").value;
  const url = api + beerage;
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(url)
    .then(reponse => {
      return reponse.json()

    })
    .then(data => {

      data.forEach((beer) => {
        const theId = beer.id;
        const theBeer = beer.name;
        const theTagline = beer.tagline;
        const theDescription = beer.description;
        const theAbv = beer.abv;
        const thePic = beer.image_url;

        const nopic = document.getElementById('imageSearch').src = "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png"

        function imgDisplay() {
          if (thePic === null) {
            return nopic;
          } else {
            return thePic;
          }
        }
        // this is the bit that needs the work im guessing
        searchBeer.innerHTML += theBeer
        searchBeerTagline.innerHTML += theTagline
        searchBeerAbv.innerHTML += "ABV: " + theAbv + "%"
        searchBeerDescription.innerHTML += theDescription
        document.getElementById('imageSearch').src = imgDisplay();

      })

    })
}
```

Comment: You should create a div for each beer... This way, you're adding every beer information at the same div... You can create them dynamically... Check it out this link and good luck.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-a-new-element-to-html-dom-in-javascript

Comment: How did you select the `searchBeer` element?

Comment: I see what's wrong with your code now. But do you want each title and tag line in a separate special formatted div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you asked to put all titles in the same div indeed:

```
// this is the bit that needs the work im guessing
searchBeer.innerHTML += theBeer
searchBeerTagline.innerHTML += theTagline
searchBeerAbv.innerHTML += "ABV: " + theAbv + "%"
searchBeerDescription.innerHTML += theDescription
```

Instead, you should use as many `searchBeer` as `beer` in data response. One popular technique is to use Template, like Reusable HTML components. There are some package for that. Here is a basic reusable component, let's say you have a search result div and at the bottom this component (HTML group of elements that are doing the same thing) in your HTML body:

```
<div id="search-result" ></div>
```

And later at the bottom:

```
<div class="beer-component" style="display:none;" >
  <div class="beer-title" ></div>
  <div class="beer-tagline" ></div>
  <div class="beer-abv" ></div>
  <div class="beer-description" ></div>
  <div class="beer-image" ><img alt="beer" /></div>
</div>
```

Now you need to clone the component multiple times, add values to them and append each component in search result container.

**EDIT --------------**

When you submit a new search, the function codes will be interpreted again. So if you don't clear the search result container well, you will have your title to add up continuously because of `+=`, `titleBeer.innerHTML += theBeer`. You need to get rid of it and put data directly `titleBeer.innerHTML = theBeer`. Now the reason that might happening (cause I don't know what your function `clear()` does), is that when selecting component template:

```
const beerComponent = document.getElementsByClassName("beer-component")[0];
```

before clearing the result container, the DOM return the first beer component that reside in search result container, instead of going at the bottom to take the template instead. That 1st component already had data, hence, doing:

```
titleBeer.innerHTML += theBeer
```

the titles keep adding together, which is wrong, instead it should be:

```
titleBeer.innerHTML = theBeer
```

So you can just clear the search results before reselecting the Template component. Here is the final code in this case:

```
function beerAsk(e) {
  // clear(); NOT SURE WHAT IT DOES, BUT I CLEAR it below
  // new elements here
  const resultContainer = document.getElementById("search-result");
  // EDIT --- CLEAR Container first
  resultContainer.innerHTML = "";

  const beerComponent = document.getElementsByClassName("beer-component")[0];
  
  const beerage = document.getElementById("BeerInputSearch").value;
  const url = api + beerage;
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(url)
    .then(reponse => {
      return reponse.json()

    })
    .then(data => {

      data.forEach((beer) => {
        const theId = beer.id;
        const theBeer = beer.name;
        const theTagline = beer.tagline;
        const theDescription = beer.description;
        const theAbv = beer.abv;
        const thePic = beer.image_url;

        const nopic = document.getElementById('imageSearch').src = "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png"

        function imgDisplay() {
          if (thePic === null) {
            return nopic;
          } else {
            return thePic;
          }
        }
        // this is the bit that needs the work im guessing
        // CHANGES HAPPEN HERE
        // Create a copy to be different DOM object from the original
        let component = beerComponent.cloneNode(true);

        let titleBeer = component.getElementsByClassName('beer-title')[0];
        let taglineBeer = component.getElementsByClassName('beer-tagline')[0];
        let abvBeer = component.getElementsByClassName('beer-abv')[0];
        let descriptionBeer = component.getElementsByClassName('beer-description')[0];
        let imgBeer = component.querySelector('.beer-image img'); // return one element

        component.style = "display: block;";
        // EDIT ---- change the += to =
        titleBeer.innerHTML = theBeer
        taglineBeer.innerHTML = theTagline
        abvBeer.innerHTML = "ABV: " + theAbv + "%"
        descriptionBeer.innerHTML += theDescription
        imgBeer.src = imgDisplay();
        imgBeer.alt = theBeer;
        
        // Now append the component in Search Result container
        resultContainer.appendNode(component);
      })

    })
}
```

And for the rest you would format the component with CSS to fit your design, or just use existing component HTML codes from a Template with CSS ready.

Comment: That works perfectly i have marked it as the answer. one follow up thing, every new search doesn't get rid of the old searches? im guessing i need to create a clear function of some sort the clear the input search and the divs? the new searches just go below the last searches and just keeps compiling a big list until you refresh

Comment: You should clear inner html of result container before appending compinents in new search, before foreach loop, like `resultContainer.innerHTML = "";` with empty string.

Comment: Again that has solved one issue but created another, the first search now wipes clear and when the second search is done the results have changed however the information duplicates so it'll show the first beer from the first search as well as the second beer, i have updated my original post to show you what i mean. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i believe the consts all need clearing as well as the html?

Comment: I'm gonna put the code in my Editor, use an existing API to simulate your use case and let you know a better way of clearing for new search

Comment: I'm updating my answer so you can see what really happen that caused this behavior

Comment: Thank you so much, you’ve been such a massive help in teaching me I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. There is many approaches on using HTML reusable components, It can be done with template in HTML code like I show you, you can add an id for template, and change id of each component in result like `component.id = "beer-" + index`, to control what you really select for clone. Components can be created in JS files instead, where code will handle the template from String of from creating element directly like `document.createElement()`. There a many JS frameworks for frontend that ease the pain of setting up an approach from scratch, like React, Angular, Vue, jQuery UI, etc.